# InfluxDB Task to Calculate/Insert Value

Tags: expression, scheduled-tasks, influxdb

I am trying to calculate/insert a value into my InfluxDB 2.0.8 on a regular interval....can this be done with a task?

For a over simplified example:  How can I evaluate `1+1` once an hour and insert the result into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are well aware of the general intrinsics of tasks and how to set up a task. The only thing missing then is how to generate data rows that do not result from querying. The method `array.rows()` comes handy for this.

Here is an example - I did not try it.

```
import "array"
option task = {name: "oneplusone", every: 1h}

array.from(rows: [
    {_time: now(), _measurement: "calculation", _field: "result", _value: 1+1}
])|> to(bucket: "mybucket")
```